# Text Input On Safari Keeps Breaking The Words

Tags: text, input, safari

On Windows 10, multiple versions of Safari I see words "broken" in a textbox. It works fine in other browsers.

[image: text input on safari]

I've tried a number of css properties such as word-wrap, word-break, white-space but none have worked.

Any solutions?

Comment: What OS are you on? And what version of Safari?

Comment: @MatthewD Windows 10. I'm using an older version of safari but I actually took a walk down to the apple store here in nyc and tested it. It's doing the same thing on those new computers.

Comment: Is that a standard text box? What language is your webpage written in? Does it not do this in other browsers?

Comment: Only in safari for some reason